# Determine the set $A$ of value of $x$ for which the series converges point wise

Tags: calculus

Determine the set $A$ of value of $x$ for which the series converges point wise, and whether convergence is uniform on $A$. If not , determine a set $B⊂A$ such that the series converges uniformly on $B$

$∑_{n=1}^∞e^{nx}  cos⁡(nx) $

I know that $|cos(nx)| \leq 1$ so $|e^{nx}  cos⁡(nx)| \leq e^{nx}$.

Use the ratio test we got $D_n = \frac{e^{(n+1)x}}{e^{nx}}=e^x<1$  if $x<0$.

So $∑_{n=1}^∞e^{nx}$ converges when $x<0$.

Since $∑_{n=1}^∞e^{nx}$ converges, using the M-test, we can say that $∑_{n=1}^∞e^{nx}  cos⁡(nx) $ is uniformly converges on $(-\infty, 0)$. Is this the set $B$ or $A$? I think it's $B$ but I don't know how to find $A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument you used above shows that the series converges pointwise (in fact, absolutely) on $(-\infty,0)$.  You could also easily show the series does not converge for $x\ge 0$. So the pointwise convergence set is $A=(-\infty,0)$.

The $M$-test will only show for *fixed* $x_0<0$, that the series converges uniformly on $(-\infty, x_0]$.  You need to show the relevant inequalities hold here. That is, you need to show for $x_0<0$ that $|e^{nx}\cos(nx)|\le |e^{nx_0} |$ for all $x\le x_0$.

The series *does not* converge uniformly on $(-\infty, 0)$, since the terms of the series are not uniformly convergent to $0$ on $(-\infty,0)$) (consider the value of the $n$'th term of the series at $x_n=-1/n$).

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand your first paragraph, but for the rest I'm not sure I understand it very well, can you explain it  a little bit further please.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif For the $M$-test, you need fixed numbers $M_n\ge 0$ such that $|f_n(x)|\le M_n$ for all $x$ in some set $C$. Then if $\sum M_n$ converges, the series $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $C$.  Here, with $f_n(x)=e^{nx}\cos(nx)$, and for a fixed $x_0<0$, you have $|f_n(x)|\le M_n=e^{nx_0}$ for all $x\le x_0$. Since $\sum e^{nx_0}$ converges, the series $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $(-\infty, x_0)$.

Comment: But $\sum f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $(-\infty,0)$. If it did, then the sequence $(f_n)$ would converge to $0$ uniformly on $(-\infty,0)$ (You asked a question about the proof of this recently). Here, we have for each $n$ that $f_n(-1/n)=\cos(-1)/e$. This implies that $(f_n)$ does not converge to $0$ uniformly on $(-\infty,0)$.